# npm uninstall doesn't really uninstall on azure

Tags: git, node.js, azure

I'm using Windows Azure. In my local repository I deleted db-mysql with

```
npm uninstall db-mysql
```

When I try to push repository it gives that error. I know db-mysql is not supported by windows but I can't delete that package. What should I do?

```
remote: The node.js application will run with the default node.js version 0.6.20.
remote: 
remote: > db-mysql@0.7.6 install C:\DWASFiles\Sites\lpserver\VirtualDirectory0\site\wwwroot\node_modules\db-mysql
remote: > node-waf configure build
remote: 
remote: 'node-waf' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
remote: operable program or batch file.
remote: An error has occurred during web site deployment.
remote: npm ERR! db-mysql@0.7.6 install: `node-waf configure build`
remote: npm ERR! `cmd "/c" "node-waf configure build"` failed with 1
remote: npm ERR! 
remote: npm ERR! Failed at the db-mysql@0.7.6 install script.
remote: npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the db-mysql package,
remote: npm ERR! not with npm itself.
remote: npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
remote: npm ERR!     node-waf configure build
remote: 
remote: npm ERR! You can get their info via:
remote: npm ERR!     npm owner ls db-mysql
remote: npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
remote: 
remote: npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
remote: npm ERR! command "node" "D:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "--production"
remote: npm ERR! cwd C:\DWASFiles\Sites\lpserver\VirtualDirectory0\site\wwwroot
remote: npm ERR! node -v v0.6.20
remote: npm ERR! npm -v 1.1.37
remote: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
remote: npm ERR! message db-mysql@0.7.6 install: `node-waf configure build`
remote: npm ERR! message `cmd "/c" "node-waf configure build"` failed with 1
```

Comment: did you delete it from your package.json?  You can do that automatically by doing `npm uninstall db-mysql --save`

Comment: I deleted it manually then created new website from azure and commit again, but nothing changed. It reaches db-mysql from somewhere. I couldn't find

Answer (score 0):

In the root of your repository you should have a `package.json` file, edit that file to remove the reference to `db-mysql`, then commit the change and push the updated repository.